# Long Polling: Notifications in every browser

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-polling

I am starting a long polling request for every page of my website. It looks every second at the database and if there is something new it marks it as seen and outputs the notification. The calling JavaScript is then starting a new ajax request.

Now I got problems having opened multiple tabs on the website, because only one will recieve a new notification. This is also a problem cross-browser with the same username logged in...

What would be the smartest way to solve this fool-proof?

Than you for your input!

Comment: when you are using `websockets` like stackoverflow does, you wouldn't require polling. You could send out the notification to all listeners(active sessions), and once a listener is notified, you can locally clear notification and check if there are any other sessions of the same user. If there aren't clear notification from database _too_. I am not posting this as answer because I understand `websockets` isn't actually `ajax & long-polling`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to avoid browser pulling. You will have browsers problems and also your infrastructure should be huge to support it.

Try a server side pushing tech like [Commet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29),

> Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request
>   allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser
>   explicitly requesting it.

Other approach could be using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).